# how to use a count case as a condition in an sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I use the count case when to be condition of an sql query to search.

```sql
SELECT Branches.name AS Branches_name, Branches.code AS Branches__code ,
(COUNT(CASE WHEN products_carried_per_branches.carried = 1 THEN 1 END )) AS carried , 
(COUNT(CASE WHEN products_carried_per_branches.carried = 0 THEN 1 END )) AS unCarried
FROM branches INNER JOIN products_carried_per_branches ON (products_carried_per_branches.company_id = branches.company_id
AND products_carried_per_branches.branch_code = branches.code )
WHERE (
Branches.company_id =200017
AND Branches.deleted =0
AND products_carried_per_branches.deleted =0`

AND (COUNT(CASE WHEN products_carried_per_branches.carried = 1 THEN 1 END )) = 35

GROUP BY code
```

this is what i got so far but. but this got an "invalid use of group function" sql error.
I hope someone can help me here.
I also have stumbled the having statement but prefer not to use it because I want to use this code as a search in a datatable.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to add a [having clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) as a count is an aggregate function. So your code would be

```
SELECT 
Branches.name AS Branches_name, 
Branches.code AS Branches__code , 
(COUNT(CASE WHEN products_carried_per_branches.carried = 1 THEN 1 END )) AS carried,  (COUNT(CASE WHEN products_carried_per_branches.carried = 0 THEN 1 END )) AS unCarried 
FROM 
branches INNER JOIN products_carried_per_branches ON (products_carried_per_branches.company_id = branches.company_id AND products_carried_per_branches.branch_code = branches.code ) WHERE ( Branches.company_id =200017 AND Branches.deleted =0 AND products_carried_per_branches.deleted =0

GROUP BY code

Having (COUNT(CASE WHEN products_carried_per_branches.carried = 1 THEN 1 END )) = 35
```